# Send image from one UIViewController to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to pass one Image that i take from gallery or camera and i want it to pass on next view.
I do it by the code.

```
    PhotoDocumentViewController *objectPhotoDocument = [[PhotoDocumentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoDocumentViewController" bundle:nil];

[objectPhotoDocument.imgSelectedPhoto setImage:finalImage];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objectPhotoDocument animated:YES];
```

Here imgSelectedPhoto is the UIImageView that i declared on next view(PhotoDocumentViewController).

But when it pushed next view. Image can not be displayed i don't know what is the problem.
Please help me.

Comment: how did you defined "imgSelectedPhoto" object? it should be allocated and strong before setting the image.

Comment: Have to pass image data or Image path of dictionary to another view controller

Comment: Yes i already defined it as strong property

Comment: Ok let me try it to pass image as data format or through dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property for `UIImage` in `PhotoDocumentViewController` as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *myImage
```

And set it with:

```
[objectPhotoDocument setMyImage:finalImage];
```

before pushing your `objectPhotoDocument`.

This way you will have a strong pointer to the `UIImage` object. And in `viewDidLoad` method of `PhotoDocumentViewController` set this object to your `UIImageView`.

```
[self.imgSelectedPhoto setImage:self.myImage];
```

Comment: you have to refer @Harry answer this is way to do this.

Comment: I did't vote any one if correct or not. Even i am new in stackoverflow so it can't allow me to do vote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the properties of view and subviews after the view controller finished loading the views, i.e. inside `viewDidLoad` function. Something like:

```
PhotoDocumentViewController *objectPhotoDocument = [[PhotoDocumentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoDocumentViewController" bundle:nil];
objectPhotoDocument.imageToSend = finalImage;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objectPhotoDocument animated:YES];
```

PhotoDocumentViewController.h

```
@interface PhotoDocumentViewController : UIViewController
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *imageToSend;
@end
```

PhotoDocumentViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     ...
     imgSelectedPhoto.image = self.imageToSend;
     ...
}
```